# get src from every <img> and set it to css as background

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

im trying to make jquery code which will get src from every image in html and set it to css for class for example number-1 and then set css for every img : visibility:hidden; I have coded function which add div before  and  will be wrapped into it. I have auto-generated html code and i dont want to edit every page.

```
var a = $('div.gallery > a > img');

for( var i = 0; i < a.length; i+=1 ) {
  a.slice(i, i+1).wrapAll('<div class="grid-img"></div>');
}

$('.grid-img').each(function(i){
  $(this).addClass('number-' + (i+1));
});
```

and then take every src from img add it to variable imgBgLink1,2,3,4 and set it as background-image for class number1,2,3,4

```
$("div.gallery a img").each(function(i){
  var imgBgLink+'(i+1)' = $(this).attr("src");
  $(".number+(i+1)").css("background-image", "url("imgBgLink+(i+1)")";
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hdP7n/)

Comment: show us html code also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your image selector is wrong, correct it to

`var a = $('div.gallery > a > img');` // image is inside anchor tag

Also you can improve your jquery script like below

```
$(function(){
 $('div.gallery > a > img').each(function(index){
    $(this).addClass('number-' + (index+1));
    $(this).wrapAll('<div class="grid-img"></div>');
 });
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hdP7n/2/)**

**EDIT** : updated as per edited post

```
$(function(){
  $('div.gallery > a > img').each(function(index){
      var num = parseInt(index)+1;
      var imageBG = $(this).attr('src')+num;
      $(this).wrapAll('<div class="grid-img number-'+num+
     '" style="background-image: url('+imageBG+')"></div>');
   });
 });
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hdP7n/12/)**

Comment: nope i described it in OP, but didnt added a code which is not working, i added it to OP now but here it is, is something like this :
    $("div.gallery a img").each(function(i){
      var imgBgLink+'(i+1)' = $(this).attr("src");
      $(".number"(i+1)).css('background', 'imgBgLink+(i+1)')
    });

Comment: thank you very much now is working :-), i dont have a 15 reputation but when i get it, i will asap tick plus 1

Answer (score 0):

Your selector is wrong:

```
var a = $('div.gallery > img > a');
```

Should be this:

```
var a = $('div.gallery > a > img');
```

And use like this:

```
for( var i = 0; i < a.length; i+=1 ) {
  a.slice(i, i+1).wrapAll('<div class="grid-img number-"'+i+'></div>');
}
```

Comment: Ok sry, copy mistake, but thats not answer. What i want is that i need to take src from every img and set it asi background:url(img-src)to class number-1,2,3,4 in sequence.
//edit : @bhushan, link for fiddle is in op